# Representation of positive integer as a linear combination of squares

Tags: number-theory, isometry

"Note that
the class number of $<1,1,9>$ is $1$ and $x^2+y^2+6z^2=3n+1$ has integer solutions. 
ic forms?

Answer (score 1):

At this point, the most valuable thing for you is examples. Below is a table from a book by Dickson; I recommend the book. Meanwhile, I put lots of material at [TERNARY](http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/~kap/)

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your material. Do you have any material that gives a good introduction to this topic?

Comment: @WuLai not sure what to recommend. What is the research paper you were reading, and why?

Comment: then you do need a fair amount about ternary forms. Start with the Dickson book and my notes: http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/~kap/Jagy_Encyclopedia.pdf

Comment: Thank you very much!